# ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

When I got an Android project from Github and run it on my Android studio, I got an error

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.kodingindonesia.mycrud"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

from this error I can't even run the apk to test and build it, so what is the right solution for such problems?

```
ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2
Add Google Maven repository and sync project
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0
Add Google Maven repository and sync project
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app
```

I hope that I can still run and edit projects that I can find,
I use Android Studio 3.4.1

Comment: You should migrate to AndroidX.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the repositories section includes a maven section with the "https://maven.google.com" endpoint. For example:

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()

    // If you're using a version of Gradle lower than 4.1, you must
    // instead use:
    //
    // maven {
    //     url 'https://maven.google.com'
    // }
    }
}
```

And for

> ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0

install com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0 repository or chnage it to the version of you have

Answer (score 1):

It is an old project. Instead of `compile` you should use `implementation` keyword. Your updated `dependencies` looks as following:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: thank you this works,

this answer and below everything works so thank you

Comment: You are welcome. If it is not difficult for you accept the answer @FaisalHalim